# Admin menus and submenus

Tags: theme-options

I created an options page for admin and displayed it as a top level menu -> `add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');`

I want to add a sub menu under the top level menu I created to display exactly the same page (to be displayed as a sub menu but open this page also when user clicks the top level menu).

Also I don't know how to add another theme page I created under this top level menu. I have read the wordpress documentation and couldn't make it, before asking here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [add_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) for adding a submenu for the extra entry. Once you add one submenu entry, by default you will have 2 subitems: the parent one (the same as the root item) and the new subitem. This is a default behavior from WordPress (replicating the parent element as the first row when you have other subpages).

Comment: Thanks Mario! Could you show me what to do in my case please? I am confused!

Comment: Checkout the add_admin function in one of my plugins - http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/offer-calc/trunk/offercalc.php#L98